# Convert a String into a List in Kotlin

Tags: string, list, kotlin, data-conversion

In kotlin, I receive from a server this list of geocoordinates as a string:

> [[45.02498, 7.55163], [45.02527, 7.55167], [45.02556, 7.55172],
> [45.02564, 7.55173], [45.02582, 7.55175], [45.02582, 7.55188],
> [45.02585, 7.55202], [45.02593, 7.55213], [45.026, 7.55218]]

How can I create a List of Pairs starting from this string? I've seen that is possible to use Regex, but I've not really understood how to use it, expecially having to deal with a starting and ending square parenthesis.

Comment: The data you've shown is valid JSON - maybe use a JSON parser/deserializer?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen You are right, following your advice I've immediately solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: Cool, you're most welcome! You should post your solution as an answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution actually was very simple, and this is an instance of code.
The string has been transformed into a JSONArray and through a `for` loop it's possible to have access to all the elements, extracting the desired data.

```
val jsonArray = JSONArray(receivedText)

for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
    val pairArray = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i)
    val latitude = pairArray.getDouble(0)
    val longitude = pairArray.getDouble(1)

    Log.d("description","Pair $i - Latitude: $latitude, Longitude: $longitude")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val jsonString = "[[45.02498, 7.55163], [45.02527, 7.55167], [45.02556, 7.55172], [45.02564, 7.55173], [45.02582, 7.55175], [45.02582, 7.55188], [45.02585, 7.55202], [45.02593, 7.55213], [45.026, 7.55218]]"

val withoutBrackets = jsonString.removeSurrounding("[", "]")
val pairs = withoutBrackets.split("], [")
val pairList: List<Pair<Double, Double>> = pairs.map {
    val coords = it.removeSurrounding("[", "]").split(", ")
    Pair(coords[0].toDouble(), coords[1].toDouble())
}

println(pairList)
```

Comment: I've tried to run this code and it caused a crash of the app. I've solved the problem converting the string into a JSON object and parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

This answer can be a solution!

```
fun parseString(str: String): MutableList<Pair<Double, Double>> {
    val pairs = mutableListOf<Pair<Double, Double>>()

    val elements = str
        .removeSurrounding("[[", "]]")
        .replace(" ", "")
        .split("],[")

    elements.forEach { element ->
        val (firstElement, secondElement) = element.split(",")
        val pair = Pair(firstElement.toDouble(), secondElement.toDouble())
        pairs.add(pair)
    }
    return pairs
}
```